# Override bootstrap font size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

I am using Bootstrap v5.0.2 but I need to override the font size to some custom value.

In the html I am using `<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Click</a>`
This gives me some predefined button sizes.
In my main .css file I have:

```
body{font-size: 22px;}
h1{font-size: 24px;}
```

I want to match the button font size to the the page font size.

What is the best way to override the font size of the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a class in your main css file . For Example

```
.pageButtonSize {  font-size: 22px !important; }
```

and then add the class to your button markup.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger pageButtonSize">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the custom size applied to all `.btn`s then in a stylesheet loaded *after* BS override the body font size by setting the value of the CSS variable and the `.btn` font size to use the variable:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  body {
    --bs-body-font-size: 22px;
  }
  
  .btn {
    font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
  }
</style>
<h1>
  heading
</h1>
<p>
  paragraph
</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  button
</button>
```

This will adjust the font size of any element that is based on the `var(--bs-body-font-size)` value.
There is **no need** to use `!important` nor an additional class name (on every single `.btn`).

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own file.css containing all styles you want to override

then, add this file to your project after bootstrap is added

Note: to make sure your styles will be applied, consider adding !important for each style for example:

```css
h1{
  font-size: 50px !important;
  }
```